# Scala reads object with nested optional property

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to write a reads for the following class

```
case class User(id: String, imageId: Option[String])
```

The JSON I have looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 1
  "image": { "id" : 2 }
}
```

However the 'image' field may not exist, or it may be null.
My reads looks like this:

```
implicit val userReader: Reads[User] = (
 (JsPath \ "id").read[String] and
 (JsPath \ "image" \ "id").readNullable[String]
) (User.apply _)
```

But this does not seem to work, I still get an error when it finds a sample with no image. 'ValidationError [...] error.path.missing [...] /image/id'

How can this be solved? I'd prefer not to create an Image class, which I'm not going to use anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue comes from the fact that you are trying to read a `String` whereas **`id` is an `Int`**. You should mind your types in your json / reader.

Two options

- if `id` is really an `Int`, read it as an `Int`
- if `id` is a `String`, change your JSON

If you still want to have a `String` in your case class, you can do :

```
(JsPath \ "image" \ "id").readNullable[Int].map(_.toString)
```

Comment: That's clearly a problem, but it didn't complain about that, since I tried an example without an image there, so it couldn't see the type mismatch.
I switched it to String, I still get the same error.

Comment: same applies for the `id` at the root

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a comma between the two elements (`"id"` and `"image"`). That's why the `/image/id` path seems to be missing for the parser.

There are all sorts of tools for validating a JSON structure, for instance https://jsonlint.com/ .
So your JSON structure should look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "image": {
        "id": 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i may be late but here is a workaround:

```
implicit val userReader: Reads[User] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "image" \ "id").readNullable[String].orElse((__ \ "dummy").readNullable[String])
) (User.apply _)
```

Not perfect but it work well

better solution would be to directly cast the Js `Reads(JsSuccess(None:Option[Int]))` inside the orElse but i haven't been able to do it...